# Laravel self relation many to many

Tags: laravel

I have table `items`(means artefacts).And artefacts (not all of them) can be created using another (one or more) artefact(s).

I can't find any working example in google how to do many to many self relation in laravel.

I wrote something like this:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'item_id');
    }

    public function components()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'component_id');
    }
}
```

But I have no idea what to do next.I stuck.Any help would be appreciated.

Here my table structure:

```
id | name | price | extra_item_slot
------------------------------------
```

But I can change it if need.For add another column or something like that.

**Upd:** One Artefact can contain multiple child Artefacts.

Comment: what is the depth of it ? Just one level or it can go many levels ? You may search for "parent/child relationship to self" - there are several examples for this.

Comment: Can you show your table structure?

Comment: @Ersoy What u mean when say levels?

Comment: So one Artefact can contain child Artefact?

Comment: If then, you have to make parent item's id in Item table like following

Comment: id | name | price | extra_item_slot | parent_id

Comment: @ZhengYu ty for helping.No.One Artefact can contain multiple child Artefacts.

Comment: @ZhengYu I know I need another table for save child artefact id's .But I don't know  how to do it because can't find any document or example about it.

Comment: @Spectr how deep your relation will be.just one parent and one child level or child can be parent of another child that can be parent of another child etc etc. that’s the depth of relationship.

Comment: @Ersoy Thank's to you I finally understood this depth of relationship :) .Maximum depth is two.For example:Artefact a, b, c can be child of artefact D.And Artefact z, y, x can be child of R. Finally R and D child of Artefact S.This is the maximum depth of my table relationship.

Comment: I think that for self relation manyToMany you should have something like `component_item` pivot table.

Comment: @Tpojka I know I need additional pivot table.But I don't know how to create it.Never do this before in self relation.And also can't find any example.

Comment: Try with making one more model `Component::class` and set table of it to be `items`. Work around that idea.

Comment: @Tpojka Actually I don't understand youre idea fully.Can you explain more detailed?

Comment: You can set another model (let's say `Component::class`) with `protected $table = 'items';` - as same table as set in `Item::class`. That way you can make easier manyToMany relation between those. Of course, you'd still need to create `component_item` table with appropriate keys in there. Another thing: for adjacency modelling check these packages if can help you [calebporzio/parental](https://github.com/calebporzio/parental) [staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list](https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list) with your requirements.

Comment: @Tpojka Ty.I will consider youre idea.

Comment: @unclexo Better to use additional pivot table but need any example of this using self relation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As you asked for an example**.

This answer is only for giving you an example of a many-to-many relationship with the same table. This is actually known as self-referencing table. So let's do it.

First, we need to create two tables. One is for the artifact names and the other one is an intermediary table which is called the pivot table. Here `parent_child` table is a pivot table.

```
Schema::create('artifacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('parent_child', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('parent_id');
    $table->foreign('parent_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('artifacts');

    $table->unsignedInteger('child_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('child_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('artifacts');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now we need to seed those two tables. For the brevity, I'm going to put them into links. Here are [ArtifactSeeder.php](https://pastebin.com/fnb36PWB) and [ParentChildSeeder.php](https://pastebin.com/rmH4TqcU)

Next up, we need to tell the model to build the many-to-many self-referencing relationship. Here is our model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Artifact extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Artifact::class,
            'parent_child',
            'parent_id',
            'child_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Now it's time to play with the data. So let's play with that.

```
$parent = Artifact::where('name', '=', 'D')->first();

// or 

$parent = Artifact::find(2);

foreach ($parent->children as $child) {
    echo $child->name . '<br>';
}
```

I think there is no need to use a many-to-many relationship in your case. You can get your expected data using one-to-many relationship as [@ZhengYu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13666163/zhengyu)'s answer. Nevertheless, you can explore whatever you want. Thanks! :)

Comment: Ty this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

You can save child artefacts using parent ID.
So child 1 and child 2 can be saved using same parent ID. 
For example,

```
id | name | price | extra_item_slot | parent_id
------------------------------------------------
1    parent  10        some              0
2    child1   2        some              1
3    child2   3        some              1
```

In above example, item 1 has 2 child - item 2 and item 3

In this case, you can define many to many relation in laravel:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'item';

    public $fillable = ['name', 'price', 'extra_item_slot', 'parent_id'];

    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Item','parent_id','id');
    }
}
```

Then you can get children items as your mind:

```
$parentItem = Item::where('name', '=', "someword")->where('parent_id', '=', "0")->first();
$childrenItems = $parentItem->children; // you can get all children here
```

Hope to helpful!

Comment: Thank's that's a good answer (+1) if I have one to many relation.But in my case I have many to many relation.So what if one child have two or more parents ?